Pull Data From Web
I am a beginner in VBA. I want to get data from website to my excel sheet through selenium edge. I write following codes but its not working. kindly help me. For your easiest I submit some consumer no like 23226286, 23225631, 23225856, 23226214, 23226197 & Location Code is 'E1'. I want get the last month data of above consumer.
Option Explicit
Private ie          As Selenium.EdgeDriver

Sub Pull_Data_With_Edge()
    
    Const url       As String = https://billonweb.bpdb.gov.bd/billInfo
    
    Dim ie          As Object
    Dim wkb         As Workbook
    Dim numberSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dataSheet   As Worksheet
    Dim currRowNumberSheet As Long
    Dim firstRowNumberSheet As Long
    Dim lastRowNumberSheet As Long
    Dim currRowDataSheet As Long
    Dim timeoutStart As Double
    Dim trNum       As Long
    Dim RNo         As Integer
    
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set numberSheet = wkb.ActiveSheet
    Set dataSheet = wkb.ActiveSheet
    RNo = numberSheet.Range("RowsCount").Value
    numberSheet.Range("O2:R" & RNo).ClearContents
    firstRowNumberSheet = numberSheet.Range("R" & RNo).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    lastRowNumberSheet = RNo
    currRowDataSheet = numberSheet.Range("R" & RNo).End(xlUp).Row
    currRowDataSheet = 1 + currRowDataSheet
    Set ie = CreateObject("Selenium.EdgeDriver")
    ie.SetProfile "Default"
    ie.Get url
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:5")
    For currRowNumberSheet = firstRowNumberSheet To 425
        ie.FindElementByClassName("form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid is-invalid ng-touched").Clear
        ie.FindElementByClassName("form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid").Clear
        ie.FindElementById("form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid is-invalid ng-touched ").SendKeys (numberSheet.Range("C" & currRowNumberSheet).Value)
        ie.FindElementById("form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid").SendKeys ("E1")
        ie.FindElementByClassName("btn btn-w-s btn-primary mr-2 ").Click
        timeoutStart = Timer * 60
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set NodeDataTable = ie.FindElementById("DataTables_Table_0 ")
            On Error GoTo 0
        Loop While NodeDataTable Is Nothing Or Timer - timeoutStart > 60
        On Error Resume Next
        dataSheet.Range("R" & currRowDataSheet) = NodeDataTable.FindElementsByTag("tr")(2).FindElementsByTag("td")(13).Text
        For trNum = 2 To 10
            If Not (NodeDataTable.FindElementsByTag("tr")(trNum).FindElementsByTag("td")(11).Text) = Empty Then
                dataSheet.Range("P" & currRowDataSheet) = NodeDataTable.FindElementsByTag("tr")(trNum).FindElementsByTag("td")(11).Text
                dataSheet.Range("Q" & currRowDataSheet) = CDate(NodeDataTable.FindElementsByTag("tr")(trNum).FindElementsByTag("td")(12).Text)
                
                dataSheet.Range("O" & currRowDataSheet) = NodeDataTable.FindElementsByTag("tr")(trNum).FindElementsByTag("td")(13).Text
                Exit For
            ElseIf NodeDataTable.FindElementsByTag("tr")(trNum).FindElementsByTag("td")(11).Text <> Empty Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next trNum
        currRowDataSheet = currRowDataSheet + 1
        Dim AllHyperlink, hyper_link As Object
        Set AllHyperlink = ie.FindElementsByTag("a")
        For Each hyper_link In AllHyperlink
            If hyper_link.Text = "Search Again" Then
                hyper_link.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next hyper_link
    Next currRowNumberSheet

End Sub


Have you checked posts on here about web scraping?

So, which line is the first that doesn't do what you intended? What is the deviation?

Quotation mark is missing in line Const url       As String = "https://billonweb.bpdb.gov.bd/billInfo".

As long as you have a CAPTCHA on the page, you can't fetch the data.

What is a CAPTCHA worth if the API is open? Nothing at all. You can access the data directly as JSON: https://billonwebapi.bpdb.gov.bd/api/BillInformation/23226197/E1
